# Keras 1.3: Error in model weights sharing with batch normalization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to pass two inputs through one model and then need concatenate both and pass through second model where weights of model1 shall be shared for both inputs as given in following code:

```python
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(input0)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
out = Flatten()(x)

model1 = Model(input0, out) 
model1 = Model(input0, out)
out_a = model1(input1)
out_b = model1(input2)

concatenated = keras.layers.concatenate([out_a, out_b])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)
model2 = Model([input1, input2], out)
```

This works without batch normalization as given above. However, if I uncomment BatchNormalization, the code gives following error:

```python
ValueError: Variable batch_normalization_5/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at
```

How I don't how to resolve this error.

The figure of complete model looks like:

[image: weights of model are same for both inputs.]

People got this error message when using multiple GPU with tensorflow 1.3, however, my error message is same but cause of error is different.

Comment: You are defining the same exact model two times, just don't.

Comment: This works without Batch-normalization but if I do batch normalization then gives error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by upgrading tensorflow 1.3 to 1.4.